# AutoCompleteTextView not showing any result in Android Version 6.0.1 or above

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have made an activity and have used AutoCompleteTextView in it. It is working fine with Android Version 6.0.0 on Emulator and on Real Phone but when I run this app on Android Version 6.0.1 or Greater then  it does not show any suggestion in emulator or in real phone. Below is the code for search activity.

```
package com.example.pakmadinaauto;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.pakmadinaauto.MainActivity.partsDatabase;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

    String selectedItem;
    TextView selectedPartTextView;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        final AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoCompleteTextView);

        selectedPartTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedPartTextView);

        ArrayList<String> partNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor cursorLocal = partsDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM parts", null);

        int partNameIndex = cursorLocal.getColumnIndex("partName");

        while(cursorLocal.moveToNext()){

            partNames.add(cursorLocal.getString(partNameIndex));

        }

        selectedItem = new String();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partNames);
        searchTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

        searchTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                selectedItem = searchTextView.getText().toString();

                cursor = partsDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE partName = '" + selectedItem + "'", null);

                //WHERE partName = '"+selectedItem+"'

                int modelIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("model");
                int catIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("cat");
                int ccpIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("ccp");
                int cpIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("cp");
                int rpIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("rp");

                if (cursor.moveToNext()){

                    selectedPartTextView.append("Part Name: " + selectedItem + "\n"
                            + "Model: " + cursor.getString(modelIndex) + "\n"
                            + "CAT: " + cursor.getString(catIndex) + "\n"
                            + "CCP: " + cursor.getString(ccpIndex) + "\n"
                            + "CP: " + cursor.getString(cpIndex) + "\n"
                            + "RP: " + cursor.getString(rpIndex));

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: Can you paste the java code?

Comment: code is as follows:

Comment: question has been updated with code